# Using an object created data-type

Tags: java

Alright so in "Money.java", I created a money object. Heres the object:

```
public Money(double amount)
{
    if (amount < 0)
    {
        System.out.println(
             "Error: Negative amounts of money are not allowed.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        long allCents = Math.round(amount*100);
        dollars = allCents/100;
        cents = allCents%100;
    }
}
```

Now, I'm trying to set a variable based on this object, but my mind must have disappeared and I'm getting this error:

```
CreditCard.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
     balance = Money(0.00);
               ^
symbol:   method Money(double)
location: class CreditCard
```

I just cant put things together and see my mistake.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `balance = new Money(0.00);`?

Comment: System.exit(1) is the error, System.exit(0) by convention is a normal exit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `new` keyword to initialize your object.

```
balance = new Money(0.00);
```

Read more about how to [create an object in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html)